# How to join 2 queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 SQL queries:

```
SELECT accounts.assigned_user_id, jt0.user_name assigned_user_name,
SUM( IF(opp.opportunity_type='2', IFNULL(opp.amount,0), 0) ) AS amt_revenue,
SUM( IF(opp.opportunity_type='4', IFNULL(opp.amount,0), 0) ) AS amt_return
FROM accounts
LEFT JOIN users jt0
ON jt0.id=accounts.assigned_user_id AND jt0.deleted=0 AND jt0.deleted=0
LEFT JOIN accounts_opportunities AS a_o
ON a_o.account_id = accounts.id AND a_o.deleted=0
LEFT JOIN opportunities AS opp
ON (opp.id = a_o.opportunity_id AND opp.deleted=0 AND opp.sales_stage = 'Closed Won' AND opp.opportunity_type IN('2', '4'))
WHERE accounts.deleted=0
GROUP BY accounts.assigned_user_id, jt0.user_name
ORDER BY SUM(IFNULL(opp.amount,0)) DESC
```

And:

```
SELECT accounts.assigned_user_id, 
SUM( IFNULL(accounts_collections.amount,0)) AS amount 
FROM accounts 
LEFT JOIN accounts_collections ON(accounts_collections.account_id = accounts.id AND accounts_collections.deleted=0) 
GROUP BY accounts.assigned_user_id
```

How can I join the 2 queries above?

Comment: Join them how? What sort of output are you attempting to get by combining them?

Comment: What output do you want to get?  Note that you cannot use `UNION` between these two queries as they are now, because you select 4 columns in query 1 and 2 columns in query 2.

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen I wanna get amt_revenue, amt_return and amount for accounts.assigned_user_id.

Comment: Dear @TimBiegeleisen: I can't enclose  my pictures. Do you have an account Skype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to put the second query into a subselect. There are two ways of doing this. In the select section or in the form section. Not sure which MySQL accepts but both work in other SQL engines.

```
SELECT 
    accounts.assigned_user_id, 
    jt0.user_name assigned_user_name,
    SUM( IF(opp.opportunity_type='2', 
        IFNULL(opp.amount,0), 0) 
    ) AS amt_revenue,
    SUM( IF(opp.opportunity_type='4', 
        IFNULL(opp.amount,0), 0) 
    ) AS amt_return,
    (
        SELECT SUM( IFNULL(accounts_collections.amount,0)) AS amount 
        FROM accounts 
            LEFT JOIN accounts_collections ON(accounts_collections.account_id = accounts.id AND accounts_collections.deleted=0) 
        GROUP BY accounts.assigned_user_id
    ) AS amount
FROM accounts
    LEFT JOIN users jt0
        ON jt0.id=accounts.assigned_user_id AND jt0.deleted=0 AND jt0.deleted=0
    LEFT JOIN accounts_opportunities AS a_o
        ON a_o.account_id = accounts.id AND a_o.deleted=0
    LEFT JOIN opportunities AS opp
        ON (opp.id = a_o.opportunity_id AND opp.deleted=0 AND opp.sales_stage = 'Closed Won' AND opp.opportunity_type IN('2', '4'))
WHERE accounts.deleted=0
GROUP BY accounts.assigned_user_id, jt0.user_name
ORDER BY SUM(IFNULL(opp.amount,0)) DESC



SELECT 
    accounts.assigned_user_id, 
    jt0.user_name assigned_user_name,
    SUM( IF(opp.opportunity_type='2', 
        IFNULL(opp.amount,0), 0) 
    ) AS amt_revenue,
    SUM( IF(opp.opportunity_type='4', 
        IFNULL(opp.amount,0), 0) 
    ) AS amt_return,
    amount_tbl.amount
FROM accounts
    LEFT JOIN users jt0
        ON jt0.id=accounts.assigned_user_id AND jt0.deleted=0 AND jt0.deleted=0
    LEFT JOIN accounts_opportunities AS a_o
        ON a_o.account_id = accounts.id AND a_o.deleted=0
    LEFT JOIN opportunities AS opp
        ON (opp.id = a_o.opportunity_id AND opp.deleted=0 AND opp.sales_stage = 'Closed Won' AND opp.opportunity_type IN('2', '4'))
    JOIN (
        SELECT accounts.assigned_user_id,
            SUM( IFNULL(accounts_collections.amount,0)) AS amount 
        FROM accounts 
            LEFT JOIN accounts_collections ON(accounts_collections.account_id = accounts.id AND accounts_collections.deleted=0) 
        GROUP BY accounts.assigned_user_id
    ) AS amount_tbl ON (amount_tbl.assigned_user_id = accounts.assigned_user_id)
WHERE accounts.deleted=0
GROUP BY accounts.assigned_user_id, jt0.user_name
ORDER BY SUM(IFNULL(opp.amount,0)) DESC
```